# Terraform failed API authorization

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

following this tutorial: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/cloud-sign-up?in=terraform/cloud-get-started#create-an-organization
i was directed to this: https://app.terraform.io/app/getting-started/example and i can't succeed in first step -

> terraform login

i copied and pasted the the token from opened website and this is the result:
│ Error: Failed to create API client: Get "https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/ping": net/http: invalid header field value "Bearer \x16" for key Authorization

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPJDA.png)
i know it looks like i provided wrong token/some typo but i tried couple of times so i have no idea how could i every time wrongly copied&pasted the token

i was following previous tutorials from Hashicorp very carefully

Comment: If you are using vs code terminal, then change this process into Powershell, vs code terminal is returning this error but Powershell doesn't

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same error and solved it by switching the terminal application I was using. Apparently the terminal in VS Code on Windows appends an extra unicode character when you paste into it. Pasting the token in Windows Powershell worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

updating version of terraform helped.  I used Chocolatey to download terraform, and it downloaded outdated version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The only way for me to get this working was to use the
"Open New *Extenal* Terminal" in VsCode ... it simply doesn't work to paste the token in the Internal Terminal in VsCode, I tried both Powershell 5.1 and 7.1, neither of them work!   VsCode seems to add some symbols to make the token invalid if pasted inside the Internal Terminal of VsCode!